# Mass down vote apparently in retaliation - Inappropriate behaviour

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I asked a question and got no answers, then I offered a bounty on my question and someone replied, but his answer was not good for me. I comment and explained why it was not good and then in return got this:

[image: what?]

A down vote for all my answers and questions in one minute.
Can I do something about it?

Comment: Without commenting on the down vote pattern, I do think your question could use some refining. The other questions which dpollit found do appear to answer most of your question other than "tell me what to buy", and see http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3957/why-is-there-so-much-hostility-to-what-should-i-buy-and-shopping-questions on that.

Comment: I agree with @mattdm on this front as well. The information given is pretty much all you would need beyond somebody walking into the store and picking the filters off the rack for you. We do have some expectation that questioners have done a little work on their own.

Comment: I did a research and found out that lee's filters considered to be the best, but could not find a good compression between their set to another. Saying something is the best isn't enough when you are looking for a cheaper solution. I would like to know what am I losing by selecting a different manufacturer. Then I can decide which is best for me in terms of quality/price.

Comment: Sorry, but I think a lot of those questions and answers have that information. For example, one of them mentions that Cokin ND filters have a color cast and Lee's do not, etc. Significant price difference usually does mean quality difference in most things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a little looking around. Moderators don't have direct access to some of this sort of information, but the SE network will take of things if the pattern is suspicious. Serial voting is such a pattern and should be reversed when the bot gets a chance to do its thing.

See this: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) for some details.

Comment: +1  Looks like 42 rep in downvotes, 22 reversed.